# How to omit nested controller names of routes in Laravel 4?

Tags: laravel, controllers

I have achieved the following route structure using nested controllers

> root/areas/eventID/titles/titlesID/sections/sectionsID

Where `resourceID` is a slug of the preceding controller and `areas`, `titles`, and `sections` are controllers.

I want my URL structure to be `root/eventID/titlesID/sectionsID`, but I'm not sure how I'd achieve this in my `routes.php` file since I need to specify the named route. So far, I have set out nested controllers like this:

```
Route::resource('areas','AreasController');
Route::resource('areas.titles','TitlesController');
Route::resource('areas.titles.sections','SectionsController');
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You can add a route like: `Route::get('{eventID}/{titlesID}/{sectionsID}', 'MyController@myMethod');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a [route with parameters](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-parameters).

```
Route::resource('{eventID}/{titlesID}/{sectionsID}', 'MyController');
```

Then in your `MyController` you will have something like this:

```
<?php

class AuthController extends BaseController {

    public function get()
    {
        // Your code...
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Rubens. Making the controllers nested was needlessly complicating things.